# Pip cache is too big, can I move it to other drives?

Tags: python, pip

Now this only happens when you starting to cloning a lot of AI projects
Every project download a different version of torch and CUDA and fill all spaces in default pip cache on C drive

How can we move it to other location?

I found this [https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/#:~:text=Step%206%3A%20Configuration&text=Pip%20also%20contains%20a%20legacy,using%20the%20environment%20variable%20PIP_CONFIG_FILE](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/#:%7E:text=Step%206%3A%20Configuration&text=Pip%20also%20contains%20a%20legacy,using%20the%20environment%20variable%20PIP_CONFIG_FILE).

It says pip.ini is at %HOME%\pip\pip.ini
However when I paste %HOME% into address bar it even says I do not have that folder

Comment: Try using the Win+R keyboard shortcut to open the "run dialog",  type:   `explorer.exe "%HOME%"`   into the dialog box, and then hit the enter key.

Comment: @svin83W Well I found that the "%HOME%" is just C:\Users\administrator\Documents, and no pip.ini found

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the pip.ini location at this path: `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`

Alternatively if your project are located on your other drive, you can create a virtual environment for each of your project using `python -m venv venv` and then activate it to install the packages inside. You can then clean the pip cache by using `pip purge`.